# Characteristic function of a divisibility sieve (like Eratosthenes) is periodic for finite sieving set.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, divisibility, integers, sieve-theory

Let $a_n \in \Bbb{R}, n \in \Bbb{Z}$ be a bi-infinite sequence.  For any set $T\subset \Bbb{Z}$, define a *divisibility sieve* $\widehat{T}$ to be a transformation of the sequence that deletes every element $a_{tm}$ for all $t \in T$, $m \in \Bbb{Z}$.  Define the characteristic function of $\widehat{T}$ to be $\chi_T(n) = 1$ if $n \in T\Bbb{Z} = \cup_{t \in T} t\Bbb{Z}$ and $0$ otherwise.

*Then $\chi_T(n)$ is periodic if and only if $T$ is contained in a finite union of prime ideals of $\Bbb{Z}$.*

Any idea how to prove this?  Seems true.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote.  $T$ need not be finite, so I've modified to say $T \subset $ some finite union of ideals of $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: This is interesting; how does this compare with https://everything2.com/title/Odd-Even+Theorem?

Comment: @abiessu I don't see the relation, myself.  But of course it's all part of number theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The period will be the lowest common multiple of the generators of the ideals making up the union.

However, for the converse, if $T=\{5\}$ then $\chi_T$ is periodic, but in what sense is $T$ a union of ideals? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I think you can prove that if $T$ is contained in a finite union of proper ideals, then in fact $\cup_{t\in T}t\mathbb{Z}$ *is* a finite union of proper ideals. Obviously it's true if $T$ is finite, otherwise, suppose $T\subset \cup_{u\in U}u\mathbb{Z}$, you can show that $\cup_{t\in T}t\mathbb{Z}\subseteq\cup_{u\in U}u\mathbb{Z}$, and that if they aren't equal, there's an element you can remove from $U$ and preserve the relation. I think.

Comment: I'm afraid it just seemed intuitive, so I don't have a reference anywhere, sorry. I remember that when I studied ring theory in uni, the structure of the ring $\mathbb Z$ made a lot of sense, maybe because of too much time as a kid playing with numbers. 

As for an iff condition, I think your statement *$\chi_T$ is periodic iff $T$ is contained in a finite union of ideals* is correct. The proof outline given here *should* work (I think). Or, you could note that $\{x:\chi_T(x)=1\}$ is a finite union of cosets $\cup(y+m{\mathbb{Z}})$, $m$ is the period, and $0\leq y<m$.

Comment: Then, maybe prove $T\mathbb{Z}=U\mathbb{Z}$ where $U=\{m,y_1,y_2,\dots,y_k\}$.